# Extract distribution for forecast values from auto.arima

Tags: time-series

Forecast(model) from Forecast package, it returns point forecast along with upper and lower forecast intervals. Is there a way to extract the exact distribution for each forecast value so that I can make a histogram for every row of forecast? Having the intervals are't sufficient enough to make histograms shown below.

```
> forecast(mod,12)
   Point Forecast        Lo 80        Hi 80        Lo 95        Hi 95
12    0.000284821 0.0002356356 0.0003340064 2.095985e-04 0.0003600435
13    0.000284821 0.0002237453 0.0003458967 1.914137e-04 0.0003782283
14    0.000284821 0.0002138190 0.0003558230 1.762328e-04 0.0003934092
15    0.000284821 0.0002051195 0.0003645225 1.629281e-04 0.0004067140
16    0.000284821 0.0001972803 0.0003723617 1.509390e-04 0.0004187030
17    0.000284821 0.0001900876 0.0003795544 1.399388e-04 0.0004297033
18    0.000284821 0.0001834037 0.0003862383 1.297167e-04 0.0004399253
19    0.000284821 0.0001771339 0.0003925081 1.201278e-04 0.0004495142
20    0.000284821 0.0001712096 0.0003984324 1.110674e-04 0.0004585746
21    0.000284821 0.0001655793 0.0004040627 1.024565e-04 0.0004671855
22    0.000284821 0.0001602030 0.0004094390 9.423428e-05 0.0004754077
23    0.000284821 0.0001550494 0.0004145927 8.635240e-05 0.0004832896
```

Answer (score 1):

The distribution is normal for all ARIMA models provided the residuals are normally distributed. So you can easily obtain the mean and variance of all future time periods from the point forecast and upper/lower bounds.

If you are unwilling to assume the residuals are normal, you can simulate the future distributions as follows.

```
library(forecast)
nsim <- 1000
mod <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
sim <- matrix(NA, nrow=9, ncol=nsim)
for(i in 1:nsim)
  sim[,i] <- simulate(mod, nsim=9, future=TRUE, bootstrap=TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for(i in 1:9)
  hist(sim[i,], breaks="FD", main=paste("h=",i))
```

[image]

Comment: Since the theoretical forecast variance critically depends upon the Psi weights I would think that the variance/dispersion would possibly change over the forecast horizon..

Comment: It does. Look at the scale.